# How to create a note with Attributes"ReminderTime"

Tags: vb.net, evernote, reminders, evernote-app-notebook

I want to create a note with reminder, this is my code:

```
'Create a note locally.
Dim myNote As New Note()

myNote.Title = "Sample note with Reminder set"
myNote.Content = "Hello, world - this note has a Reminder on it."
myNote.Attributes.ReminderTime = DateTime.Now.ToEdamTimestamp()

'Create the note in the service, in the user's personal, default notebook.
Dim store As ENNoteStoreClient =ENSessionAdvanced.SharedSession.PrimaryNoteStore
Dim resultNote As Note = store.CreateNote(myNote)
```

but it didn't work. The error code:

```
myNote.Attributes.ReminderTime = DateTime.Now.ToEdamTimestamp()
```

Full details:

> 未处理System.NullReferenceException       HResult=-2147467261
>         Message=未将对象引用设置到对象的实例。

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: sorry, I don't understand you.Could you please explain in detail again?

Comment: `myNote.Attributes` is probably null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A note's attributes are a `NoteAttributes`object, so you have to create the object first:

```
'Create a note locally.
Dim myNote As New Note()

myNote.Title = "Sample note with Reminder set"
myNote.Content = "Hello, world - this note has a Reminder on it."

'Create the note's attributes.
Dim myNoteAttributes As New NoteAttributes

myNoteAttributes.ReminderTime = DateTime.Now.ToEdamTimestamp()
myNote.Attributes = myNoteAttributes    

'Create the note in the service, in the user's personal, default notebook.
Dim store As ENNoteStoreClient =ENSessionAdvanced.SharedSession.PrimaryNoteStore
Dim resultNote As Note = store.CreateNote(myNote)
```

Comment: yes,it did work perfectly,thanks.Where can I find some tutorials like this?

Comment: Unfortunately there aren't any tutorials available for the Evernote Windows SDK. But you can ask more questions here if needed.

Comment: Also, since my answer worked for you, it would be great if you could identify my answer as the Accepted answer.  Thanks!